# Draw Bézier curve between two related TreeViewItems

Tags: c#, wpf, events, treeview, treeviewitem

I want to draw some Bézier curve inside a canvas on the left side of a treeview to display refrerences between items. I did implement a TreeView with lazy loading and mvvm based on a tutorial from [Josh Smith](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode).

[This is Minimum example how it should look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNpEn.png)

To draw the line I want use a canvas element. So I need the correct coordinate of a TreeViewItem relative to TreeView. I didt get the screenPosition using the Initialized Event.

```
private static void OnTreeViewItemIsInitialized(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Only react to the Selected event raised by the TreeViewItem
    // whose IsSelected property was modified.  Ignore all ancestors
    // who are merely reporting that a descendant's Selected fired.
    if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, e.OriginalSource))
        return;

    TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
    var parent = item.Parent;

    var point = item.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
    var treeViewItemViewModel = item.DataContext as TreeViewItemViewModel;
    if (treeViewItemViewModel != null)
        treeViewItemViewModel.Coordinate = point;
}
```

Two challanges Iam running into using this Code: first i only get the screenposition, second I dont know how to get the parent of TreeViewItem to get calculate the correct position.

Maybe Iam on the wrong way to solve my problem? I did found some example to do something similar, but no example for a spline between two TreeViewItems of the same TreeView.

Comment: Did you mean a **Bézier** curve?

Comment: Yes of Course Bézier curve